# Please review my connection log errors

Tags: security, tails, socks

I am using the current version of Tails.  I more often than not get the warning icon at the bottom left of the connection window telling me that the log file has been copied to the clip board.  I will eventually connect with a green onion yet it takes quite a bit of time.  I could use some feedback on this log. This log is from today at around 1pm,  so the date/time is wrong. Also, there were so many repeats of the first line that I had to delete most of them in order to make them this post fit here on this forum.

```
02/12/2016 00:09:47.800 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1. 
02/12/2016 00:09:56.900 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
02/12/2016 00:09:56.900 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
02/12/2016 00:09:56.900 [NOTICE] Opening DNS listener on 127.0.0.1:5353 
02/12/2016 00:09:56.900 [NOTICE] Opening Transparent pf/netfilter listener on 127.0.0.1:9040 
02/12/2016 00:09:56.900 [NOTICE] Renaming old configuration file to "/etc/tor/torrc.orig.1" 
02/12/2016 00:09:57.200 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1. 
02/12/2016 00:09:58.600 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
02/12/2016 00:09:58.600 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
02/12/2016 00:09:58.800 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 194.132.209.190:51867 ("server rejected connection") 
02/12/2016 00:10:33.900 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Transparent pf/netfilter listener on 127.0.0.1:9040 
02/12/2016 00:10:33.900 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured DNS listener on 127.0.0.1:5353 
02/12/2016 00:06:38.900 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
02/12/2016 00:06:38.900 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
02/12/2016 00:06:39.000 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 198.23.141.168:58693 ("server rejected connection") 
02/12/2016 00:06:39.000 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 194.132.209.158:44912 ("server rejected connection") 
02/12/2016 00:06:39.400 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection 
02/12/2016 00:06:39.500 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus 
02/12/2016 00:06:39.800 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'consolsmeringue' (fresh): $9B1E39F667DBD7749CC653A7B2632A9D75DB1D27~consolsmeringue at 45.55.174.204 
02/12/2016 00:06:39.800 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no usable consensus. 
02/12/2016 00:06:40.000 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus 
02/12/2016 00:06:40.900 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no usable consensus. 
] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a filter for sure. You're using bridges, and they're filtered. Add some extra bridges WITH keys and try again

Comment: Thank you for your input.  Can you explain to me what a filter is and where it is/who is implementing it?  I thought the entire reason for a bridge was to avoid being filtered.  Furthermore, I can eventually connect with a green onion and my test to test the connection does pass. Yet does this log indicate that I can't trust the way I'm being connected?

Comment: @Toraclease the windows defender, firewall or an antivirus software are the first points to check. If with firewall disabled and antivirus software disabled you will still have such problems - then your ISP/conection are to blame and your thesis about not trusting your connection is right.

Comment: I am using Tails.  There should be no such problem.

Comment: @Toraclease Then it's a 90% probability that it's your ISP/connection filter. Try to use another connection like 3G usb modem to test if it will work and if it will seed up. If the alternate connection will help you, then you will have a 100% proove that your ISP is tampering your connectin.

Comment: Tested on a public wifi and I'm getting the same exact log entries.  I am using a preliminary Tails Micro SD (not made with the Tails installer rather the universal USB installer) I don't know if that's relevant here.  I'll go into why I'm forced to use this if it's relevant. 

It seems I must be using an adulterated Tails installation.  I downloaded the iso via a torrent which I thought was fool-proof.  I did not check SHA or PGP because I didn't think I had to with a torrent.  Should I share the torrc and torsocks.conf file contents?  Might the answer be in these files?

Comment: forgot to ask - shouldn't I have IPV6 disabled?  and if not, should I be using a IPv6 bridge? does that have any relevance here?

Comment: @Toraclease it seems to be no problem with IPv6, as far as I tested it. If your connection gives your IPv4 - disable IPv6 on it, just to keep things unified. By the way - is other connectivity runs fine? Like `wget`, `nslookup`,`ping` ? Is it a tor-only problem? Share your configs, please - they will help. `torrc` and `torsocks.conf` will be fine to start

Comment: torrc:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/sv3tlulpswchd6f/torrc.txt?dl=0

torsocks.conf:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/tffgaa43ft3yi7d/torsocks1.txt?dl=0

Comment: @Toraclease well, it starts to make sense now : your configs ARE weird. Add `VirtualAddrNetworkIPv4 127.42.42.0/24` and `SocksPolicy accept 127.0.0.0/8` and `SocksPolicy accept x.y.z.v/32` where `x.y.z.v` is your interface static IP for all of your static addresses. Let's take a look what will happen

Comment: @Toraclease add it to your `torrc`

Comment: This is a intermediary Tails installation on a Micro SD card. During Tails startup, I set a root password at the intro window so I can make changes - Once Tails has loaded, I use the root terminal to take ownership of the  torrc file so I can modify it (I don't know if this is what I'm suppose to do - if I don't do this, I don't know how else to modify the file as the amnesia user does not have permission.)  This torrc file is located at  etc/tor.  I modify it, then reboot, and my changes are gone and I'm back to the previous config.

Comment: @Toraclease try ARMBIAN or a Debian distro for your hardware

Comment: Do you mean to use something like Linux Mint to create the Tails SD/USB?

Comment: @Toraclease what is your hardware?

Comment: It depends on the day.  For now, it's a dual-core HP Windows 7 laptop bought used to be a throw-away.  I just finished installing Linux Mint.  I was also considering Ubuntu MATE instead of mint?  When booted into Mint, I cannot reach the Tails site via Firefox to do anything such as download the iso as I am getting an untrusted connection window.

Comment: I have been unable to produce a working Tails USB on Linux Mint.  I have tried many times using both command line and the software management front end yet always running into a some sort of road block. While I'm brand new to Linux, it should not be this problematic. I've been successful only at installing Tor on Linux Mint directly.  Could you take a look at this folder's contents from this Tor installation and tell me if something is out of the ordinary? I will try a different distro to get Tails working or go with Whonix.  

https://www.dropbox.com/s/dyak7r4nsglwh7k/Browser.tar.gz?dl=0

Comment: @Toraclease seems to be fine, you better add port forwarding to your linux computer and add `ClientOnly 0`, `ORPort <your lan ip>:<port>` and `ExitPolicy reject *:*` - being a mid node speeds you up ALOT, but it should be fine without it too

Comment: Thank you Alexey. Help me out here as I am very new to this - where am I suppose to add that command you gave me.   in Linux or at the router? and how do I do this?  Thanks.

Comment: @Toraclease in your `torrc`. You can use a `-f </path/to/file>` when executing a tor binary to override a default config location, by the way - that's for a case if you will have problems running it "as is"

Comment: Alexey you are incredible.  This place is very fortunate to have you.  Thank you for all you do.  I'd totally lock you in the basement.  You're worth it.