# been tampered? been filtered ? or just a network settings messing around?

Tags: connection

I'm using qubes for some times now.

after some weeks to correctly configure my setup, I want to figure it out why sys-whonix is not working correctly with my setup.

so I closely look at the other threads with one same criteria, the message in the logs : ("server rejected connection")

[one](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/9809/please-review-my-connection-log-errors) in particular attracted my attention. So I've tested some advices on this same website. So I've connected through the wifi access point from my phone and through my LAN wired network. The differences are heavy.

first some informational point:

- the LTE data network and my VDSL2 Line are from the same provider which is Proximus in Belgium (important point to dissipate any doubt about the fact if I'm in a restricted area or not).
- My LAN Network is organised with VLANs through managed switches and then through a router which is connected wiredly to an ISP box/router but its my router which does the PPPOE connection not the ISP box.
- I didn't do a DMZ zone for this qubes client but the router/firewall rules are pretty basics
- My work/personal life are sort of mixed with the justice department and to my knowledge there are no specific filters from ISP in belgium but I could be wrong if I am don't hesitate to correct me.
- I have pinged all the bridges and all except one answered.

So here are the logs through the LTE access point:

```
Events (TOR/ARM NOTICE - ERR):
 12:48:28 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to xxxxxxxxx:xxxxx ("server rejected connection") [2 duplicates hidden]
 12:48:28 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to xxxxxxxxx:xxxxx ("server rejected connection") [2 duplicates hidden]
 12:48:28 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to xxxxxxxxx:xxxxx ("server rejected connection") [2 duplicates hidden]
 12:28:55 [NOTICE] Tried for 120 seconds to get a connection to [scrubbed]:80. Giving up. (waiting for rendezvous desc) [1 duplicate hidden]
 12:28:35 [NOTICE] New control connection opened. [7 duplicates hidden]
 12:26:34 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1. [3 duplicates hidden]
 12:26:30 [WARN] Socks version 71 not recognized. (Tor is not an http proxy.)
 12:26:29 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 100%: Done
 12:26:29 [NOTICE] Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functionality is working.
 12:26:28 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit
 12:26:28 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'niffierlaterals' (fresh): $F68BBB77DA245790969057EE608E6B14283655EB~niffierlaterals at xxxxxxxxx:xxxxx
 12:26:27 [ARM_NOTICE] Unable to prepopulate bandwidth information (insufficient uptime)
 12:26:27 [ARM_WARN] The torrc differs from what tor's using. You can issue a sighup to reload the torrc values by pressing x.
   - configuration values are missing from the torrc: HiddenServiceStatistics, RunAsDaemon
 12:26:27 [ARM_NOTICE] Tor is preventing system utilities like netstat and lsof from working. This means that arm can't provide you with connection information. You can change this by adding 'DisableDebuggerAttachment 0' to
   your torrc and restarting tor. For more information see...
   https://trac.torproject.org/3313
 12:26:27 [ARM_NOTICE] No armrc loaded, using defaults. You can customize arm by placing a configuration file at '/home/user/.arm/armrc' (see the armrc.sample for its options).
```

here are from the wired network

```
 13:12:53 [NOTICE] Tried for 120 seconds to get a connection to [scrubbed]:0. Giving up. [60 duplicates hidden]
 13:12:53 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 100%: Done
 13:12:53 [NOTICE] Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functionality is working.
 13:12:53 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit
 13:12:53 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 80%: Connecting to the Tor network
 13:12:51 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus
 13:12:50 [NOTICE] Tried for 120 seconds to get a connection to [scrubbed]:0. Giving up. (waiting for circuit) [69 duplicates hidden]
 13:10:39 [NOTICE] Tried for 120 seconds to get a connection to [scrubbed]:443. Giving up. [2 duplicates hidden]
 13:09:58 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to xxxxxxxxx:xxxxx ("server rejected connection")
 13:09:58 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to xxxxxxxxx:xxxxx ("server rejected connection")
 13:09:58 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to xxxxxxxxx:xxxxx ("server rejected connection")
 13:08:21 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to xxxxxxxxx:xxxxx ("TTL expired")
 13:08:21 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to xxxxxxxxx:xxxxx ("TTL expired")
 13:07:54 [ARM_WARN] The torrc differs from what tor's using. You can issue a sighup to reload the torrc values by pressing x.
   - configuration values are missing from the torrc: HiddenServiceStatistics, RunAsDaemon [2 duplicates hidden]
 13:07:54 [ARM_NOTICE] Reconnected to Tor's control port [1 duplicate hidden]
 13:07:50 [ARM_NOTICE] Tor control port closed [1 duplicate hidden]
 12:26:27 [ARM_NOTICE] Unable to prepopulate bandwidth information (insufficient uptime)
 12:26:27 [ARM_NOTICE] Tor is preventing system utilities like netstat and lsof from working. This means that arm can't provide you with connection information. You can change this by adding 'DisableDebuggerAttachment 0' to
   your torrc and restarting tor. For more information see...
   https://trac.torproject.org/3313
 12:26:27 [ARM_NOTICE] No armrc loaded, using defaults. You can customize arm by placing a configuration file at '/home/user/.arm/armrc' (see the armrc.sample for its options).
```

So with the LTE network I had immediately a connection. Between the two tests I've of course restart tor and ask it to reconnect. When I was on the wired network like always, I had some but mostly no connection. You can notice it in the logs and through the timestamp too.

So is it my ISP preventing me to go to Tor? Is it a problem with my router setup ? Is it something else in my wired networked? Does these messages of server rejected connection come from the bridge itself or is it a generic message from ARM? What should I do to have access permanently to Tor through my wired network? Which tests should I do and how to proceed? Should I add pages and pages of bridges?

Here is the configuration of tor user configuration file from sys-whonix.

```
DisableNetwork 0
UseBridges 1
ClientTransportPlugin obfs2,obfs3 exec /usr/bin/obfsproxy managed
ClientTransportPlugin obfs4 exec /usr/bin/obfs4proxy

bridge obfs4 xxxxxxxxx:xxxxx 4F815C00771B178C0EB06FDB7293BDB1BD353E03 cert=VaCBcwj1MO3waCsl+Yq/Vuu20dP7fKI92fsvpoMTqlkOHROk/RnX4tx1oFhP7E9YWaOZFA iat-mode=2
bridge obfs4 xxxxxxxxx:xxxxx 08077A0B1248B8FC1E7C114771D3C7A9A3954D71 cert=0jrTOIV/73tSsFwi79k4Vo5rNkmIdK39SlNgv/JUOTS/yRFzeyuSr4DrkwF+Wj+lTJnHSg iat-mode=2
bridge obfs4 xxxxxxxxx:xxxxx E58F54184935689AC7BFD983FB887AFE2D443B4D cert=S+0Tez9y9+q6LUsi658pYXzDHfS+dpSS8UHMsy3OXQvuvA8GtnoQNkWG1KmihXZqt6Yqdg iat-mode=2


bridge obfs3 xxxxxxxxx:xxxxx F4B33297F39EC5CF2EFD0E3D2F3EB87EC8428237
bridge obfs3 xxxxxxxxx:xxxxx 2C3FDA0289A5627ECB582C0A61620780473A46FD

bridge obfs4 xxxxxxxxx:xxxxx F68BBB77DA245790969057EE608E6B14283655EB cert=lxPxDTtghn56dGKbQ2vicevpXiUHNzJpSxCLMd76A8MhbKPVQqurd9Uf4sx7yOfYDA5dBw iat-mode=0
bridge obfs4 xxxxxxxxx:xxxxx F4B33297F39EC5CF2EFD0E3D2F3EB87EC8428237 cert=Ax+LafRJEU1v5BGdXV0To86Vs+gr+EPbIvOZE3iL/fAY3pxScQppxW5y8e03DSCJuqZlCA iat-mode=0
bridge obfs4 xxxxxxxxx:xxxxx D28E0345809AE4BAC903EF7FC78CAAF111A63C58 cert=DtNNYXeRG4ds+iTM7sdbJHJgH7RmxDb1lt8JR17BiT7eHnORyn+4y+RcoqAI65XGvhXKJg iat-mode=0
```

I've added some bridges of different kind based on the advices here. And all the addresses come from whonix.

Comment: ftr you can consolidate both `ClientTransportPlugin` lines to `ClientTransportPlugin obfs3,obfs4 /usr/bin/obfs4proxy` but it looks like some of your bridges are down. "pinging" them won't help judge if the actual bridge and pluggable transport is available.

Comment: I would hazard a guess though, that if both are using the same set of bridges (on LTE is manages to get at least one descriptor and a working circuit), and one of them connects and the other doesn't, that there is a problem in the network configuration either within Qubes or upstream on the wired network.

Comment: Yeah, I'm totally ready to believing it but I can't think about one single settings that could intervene specifically on this thing and have that king of repercussions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like wired connection is censored or **very slow** while reaching the bridges. You don't need `DisableNetwork 0` in most of the cases - it is zero from the very beginning, unlsess explicitly set to 1. Any ARM_XXX message is ARM related, not tor related, so they're not a concern at all. One question to clarify the things - wh do you need a bridges on wired connection? On mobile connection - yes, the reason is quite ubiquitous, but why don't you use direct connection on wired? However, it must work at least faster on wired rather than on mobile even with the same bridges. What the hardware do you have on wired connection? Please attach the data requested - and I'll be glad to help you further!

Comment: So sorry for the delay of answer.

Comment: Bridges was to test to see if problems go away. Since then I have a clean install again and still have problems. The circuits according to onioncircuits doesn't Last very long. How is it supposed to be? For hardware point of view laptop -> basic switch on untagged vlan -> ubiquiti managed switch on tagged and untagged vlan -> ubiquiti router which manages vlan -> pppoe connect -> isp box

Comment: ubiquiti is a CRAPWARE - just retired some of their stuff recently on one problematic case(not just tor related): tor and ANY app that uses a lot of TCP(especially the troublestarter with U-stuff, tor uses TCP) or UDP(U-stuff drops them) connections at the same time makes it lag, if you powercycle it for 20 seconds powered off - it restores the proper work for a while(18-48 hours in the case I'm referring to).  isp box that accepts pppoe is a BRAS device - they holded even 10 years ago a 500000 tcp sessions in realtime easily, so no concern. [continuing on next comment]

Comment: pppoe as well - yes, it's not THAT good as L2TP, but 20000+ TCP sessions is not a problem at all for the *protocol*. So how long your circuits are living? More than 60,120 seconds or less? Can you please give some stats for a circuit lifetime?

Comment: It s a of course a possibility that's a ubiquiti related problem but would I not have some problems then on the tor browser on a simple windows machine? Or with my numerous vms or my torrents box or even the game then? But don't worry I don't put aside this possibility but I would nt have anything to replace it so it would nt be a solution to retire my equipment. For the pppoe I don't have any other solution than that so same conclusion. How could I provide you good stats about it which would not be related to any feelings? I rarely goes to the successful state ->2 comments

Comment: I could do a video maybe based on onioncircuits? Or a gif? It's really random the number of circuits I can get. I would give anything for someone who does a video about how is it supposed to go with the circuits. Would it be related also to the fact that s the cpu is not vt-d? Or at least related to a problem with the laptop itself?

Comment: video is better. U-stuff problem seemed to be quite a tricky to pinpoint. How we has pinpointed it: if you have a good ISP-stated speed, make a static port forward and install torrent client. Go anywhere like PirateBay and pick some hot stuff 4+ Gb of size and start downloading then seeding it. You'll see the problem slowly but surely manifesting itself. VT-D should not be a problem at all: at old Pentium4 I've had 6 vm's without ANY problem with a high network load: it was a decent ASUS motherboard,properly cooled CPU and Intel GbE PCI-E NIC - zero problems! [continued]

Comment: 1 VM was RTorrent, 1 VM was Tor node, 3 VMs were webservers - no problems ever popped up!

Comment: Okey I will try to find a good solution to make a video about it. I never really seen the dropping of that kind of traffic on my router related to my seedboxes which always been on a single port forward. So how do you measure it? On the router itself with tcpdump or on the vm with something else?

Comment: https://obsproject.com/download - the best for Windows, if you use it

Comment: the drop rate - initial detect - was by lots of messages in Tor's log "timeout connecting to [scrubbed]" and "increasing timeout due to the died attempts". Torrent stress-test with RTorrent exposed it all very clear.

Comment: I didn't know it :) thanks. Don't forget that I m not under the impression to have that kind of problems with tor under other OS than the qubesOS with whonix. But I'm gonna test it under other OS too then. I will need a lot of time to test it under other conditions but as I said I think I have problems only under whonix.  Don't forget to point to me the thread on ubiquiti where you discussed maybe the tcp dropping packets problem or maybe at least you measured it.... If you don't mind of course?

Comment: I wasn't opening the support ticket on Ubiquity: tech support said that we need to use the latest firmware(we did) and an original PSU(we did as well, it was powered through the APC UPS 3000VA with 15% load), nothing more... So the tech support said that "it's an ISP problem"... We've made a router, plugged to the ISP - zero problems, speed x1.5 - x2

Comment: I don't think I have enough bandwith to really see that happening with 100mb. So I guess I will see it in 10 years when I will have 2Gbps connection. So tcpdump on router or vm to see that kind of dropping consequences?

Comment: yes, tcpdump or wireshark will show you dropped UDP and TCP sessions

Comment: On the router then? Or on the vm with the non-existence of the packet answers?

Comment: on a VM host - best place to catch it all. Even with a proper sysctl's - it's a best place "to go fishing" for results. On VM's it can be catched as well, but not that good/many/identifiable

Comment: sorry to have been long to answered, I would like to run this through you again. So the transition to fedora-26 have made things worse about the usage of whonix. And I think, but that's my deduction, there is only one thing that can altered that much the problem is an update on how vlan are managed or created.  
Someone have made me test a debian test-tor as netvm test and it bottstraps okey but not the whonix. so there has to be a problem with it and the only thing changing between the differents places where I connect is the the Vlans configuration

Comment: So I think there is the vlan management between ubiquiti and how it is resolved in fedora and whonix. so here is what I will do. I'm going to try through the vlan default runwway of ubiquiti and see if it's go through. But in the same time I would like to know how would I run a test to identify if packets are dropped or not? Exactly with tcpdump? And for that maybe, it's better to chat or that you point to which test to run through tcpdump for example.

Comment: And for the configuration of the setup I will edit my answer tomorrow to show exactly the identifies of vlans and ow it transits.

Comment: @vigilian ok, awaiting for your data.

Comment: Yeah but the problem is that I'm not used to that kind of test with tcpdump. Anyway I've made some tests and I finally don't have problem with tor but only with whonix. so I think that it's not necesseraly the ubiquiti equipment. So what you be my filters on tcpdump?